# NativeScript call to google API with OAuth2

Tags: javascript, google-oauth, nativescript, google-sheets-api

How is it possible to access a google Sheet through the Nativescript? Which library do I need to access the G-API?

Check on the internet but there are not enough example of how to access it.
I used the following code to authenticate my dummy account and it worked. I got the session token but what's next?

```
import { GoogleSignin } from '@nativescript/google-signin'
await GoogleSignin.configure()
const user = await GoogleSignin.signIn()
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have authenticated your user with the GoogleSignin module you can use the Google Sheets API to access, write, update etc. the data of the Google Sheet.

You first need to install the `@google-cloud/google-auth-library` and `@google-cloud/sheets` npm packages.

small example on how to read data from a sheet using the Google Sheets API:

```
const { GoogleAuth, GoogleAuthOptions } = require('@google-cloud/google-auth-library');
const { Sheets } = require('@google-cloud/sheets');

async function readSheet(sheetId) {
  const auth = new GoogleAuth();
  const user = new Sheets({ auth });

  const result = await user.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId: sheetId
  });
  const rows = result.data.values;
  console.log(rows);
}
```

Please keep in mind that you need to have the credentials.json file for your google account to access the sheets API and also the sheet should be shared with the email address of the service account for which you have the json-file.